# Samba share stopped working

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I have the following share on my Ubuntu machine:

```
#VERSION 2
path=/home/pitel/Videa
comment=
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:R,S-1-22-1-1000:F
guest_ok=y
sharename=Videa
```

It used to worked, but when I tried to connect to it today from my Raspberry Pi, I get the following error:

```
sudo mount -v /mnt/smb

mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.0.4,unc=\\192.168.0.4\Videa,user=,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

The `fstab` line (on RPi):

```
//192.168.0.4/Videa /mnt/smb/ cifs guest,ro 0 0
```

Log from the server (Ubuntu:)

```
[2016/11/27 17:35:57.008909,  0] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:3247(process_usershare_file)
process_usershare_file: stat of /var/lib/samba/usershares/videa failed. Permission denied
```

File permissions on Ubuntu:

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root       4,0K led  5  2016 /var/lib/samba
drwxrwx--T 2 root  sambashare 4,0K lis 27 17:33 /var/lib/samba/usershares
-rw-r--r-- 1 pitel pitel      110  lis 27 17:33 /var/lib/samba/usershares/videa
```

I did not knowingly changed anything. Might there be some recent broken upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

What is the user configured as the Guest on the SMB Server?

If you don't know, likely it is the default of `nobody`, which has no permissions on the share.

Either use the `guest account =` parameter in the share settings to set the guest account to `pitel` (if that is how you want to go)...

Or set the permissions via `chmod` on the share to be more permissive (setting the Other bit to 7 for RW or 5 for RO).

[More information is available at the samba.org docs.](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html)

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I'm trying to put back more than just lurk here these days. I guess I'm new to the format and conventions.